# jQuery wrapping of a tr td with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap my table with a new tr and then all the td's inside the wrapping tr.

My code is as follows:

```
$('.ccbnBgTblTxt td').wrap('<tr class="new"/>');
```

What I'm trying to do is.. this

```
<tr class="new"><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Right now I'm getting results like this.

```
<tr class="new"><td></td></tr><tr class="new"><td></td></tr>
```

Anyway to wrap all the td's?

Comment: And what's your (relevant) HTML?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `.wrapAll()` function

```
$('.ccbnBgTblTxt td').wrapAll('<tr class="new"/>');
```